# How do I set a custom gunicorn worker timeout when serving an MLflow model with the "mlflow models serve" CLI?

Tags: mlflow

When serving an MLflow Python model with the "pyfunc" backend (https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/mlflow/pyfunc/backend.py), how can I set a custom gunicorn worker timeout? The default timeout of 60 seconds may be insufficient when serving large models that take a long time to load.

Answer (score 5):

As of MLflow 1.2, you can set a custom gunicorn timeout by specifying the `GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS` environment variable. The following example serves a model with a worker timeout of 120 seconds

`GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--timeout 120" mlflow models serve --model-uri /path/to/model`

Answer (score -1):

mlflow allows setting these options from the cli:

Example: `mlflow models serve ... --timeout 180`

Official documentation (`mlflow models serve --help`):

> -t, --timeout TEXT   Timeout in seconds to serve a request (default: 60).